# The Insert data binding setting is required by the insert command Kendo Grid Error anyone

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-grid

Kendo Grid  show the following ERROR

The Insert data binding setting is required by the insert command. Please specify the Insert action or url in the DataBinding configuration

```html
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Pa.Portal.KazangService.KazangAccount>()
    .Name("grids")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(g => g.Id);
        columns.Bound(g=>g.UserName);
        columns.Bound(g=>g.Password);
        columns.Bound(g=>g.Channel);
       
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create()) 
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .AutoBind(true)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)      
        .Model(m => m.Id(h => h.Id))      
        .Read(read => read.Action("LoadAllkazangAccounts", "Kazang"))    
        ))

CONTROLLER


  public ActionResult LoadAll([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            IKazangBusinessService client = PaChannelFactory<IKazangBusinessService>.Default.CreateChannel();
            IEnumerable<KazangAccount> KaList = client.GetAllKazangAccounts().ToList();
            ((IChannel)client).Close();
            return Json(KaList.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

Comment: What does your code look like? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is down to the fact you have added the Create button in your toolbar.

With this added to the grid the datasource section is looking for the create command path.

eg. for your read action you have

```
.Read(read => read.Action("LoadAllkazangAccounts", "Kazang"))
```

so you need to add the appropriate insert action like:

```
.Create(create=> create.Action("CreatekazangAccounts", "Kazang"))
```

if you don't need to create anything in this grid then just remove the create toolbar menu item from the grid.

Comment: Thanks a lot , you have served  my day.Its my first  asking  a question on this forum  much appreciated

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help. if you wouldn't mind can you just  mark this as the answer.

Comment: This answer is great if you need server-side operation when the user creates a record. But there's no information about how to call something client-side instead.